# very long CSV data in excel single cell

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have a single cell in excel with CSV data. It's very long and I am trying to extract it with the following method (see below)
It has to be with a formula.
I was wondering if it would be possible to extract the number before the first comma, then the number after the second comma, then the third and so on.
Any suggestions ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has the dynamic array formula in Office 365, put this in D2:

```
=INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(B1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),SEQUENCE((LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""))+1)/5,,0)*5+SEQUENCE(,5,0)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: all i can say is "wow" !!! can't believe how quickly you came up with it. Works perfect !! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Office 365 this can also be done with the older versions of Excel.

Place the following formula in cell `D2` and then copy to `D2:H5`:

```
=MID($B$1,SEARCH("^", SUBSTITUTE(","&$B$1&",",",","^",5*(ROW()-ROW(C$2))+COLUMN(E$2)-COLUMN($D$2))),SEARCH("^", SUBSTITUTE(","&$B$1&",",",","^",5*(ROW()-ROW(C$2))+COLUMN(F$2)-COLUMN($D$2)))-SEARCH("^", SUBSTITUTE(","&$B$1&",",",","^",5*(ROW()-ROW(C$2))+COLUMN(E$2)-COLUMN($D$2)))-1)
```